# Collectstatic error on deploying django app

Tags: python, django, deployment, collectstatic

I am getting error when trying to deploy my django app (the download and installation of packages went fine):

```
     $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
   Traceback (most recent call last):
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
       settings.INSTALLED_APPS
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
       utility.execute()
       self._setup(name)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
       % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e) 
!     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
   See traceback above for details.
   You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
   Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
      $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

This is my settings.py file:

```
"""    
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*****'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["aa@bm.net"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

I have a `static` folder in the same directory as the `settings.py` file, and it is not empty. What else do I need to do to make this work?

PS: I am getting error to add more details before I post the question, what more details are needed?

Comment: Where is the paths to the static files from your django project in the test environment ?
Normally it is in the folder /var/www/media/your_project/ or similar

Comment: I actually created a separate folder for this. The path is /tmp/djcode/my_project/my_project/static. But how does that matter? The settings file is at /tmp/djcode/my_project/my_project/

Comment: Which is your static files server ? Is nginx, apache or other?

Comment: I am using Bluemix